# How get GitHub username in django-allauth after authentication?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, github, django-allauth

I added `django-allauth` to the Django project and I can authentication with GitHub on website.
After user authentication, I want to get GitHub username(a user who logged in).
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username set by `allauth` is not same as returned from github, it is the value returned from function `generate_unique_username` see it's [sourcecode](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/utils.py#L97) , so you should better access SocialAccount's extra_data field, below is sample view that shows how to access it.

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, render
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            social_account=SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user).extra_data
            return HttpResponse(social_account['login'])
        except SocialAccount.DoesNotExist: # user created with email and password
            return HttpResponse(request.user.username)
    return HttpResponse("<a href='/accounts/github/login/'>Sign Up</a>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for account in user.socialaccount_set.all %}

    <p>Username: <a target="_blank"
                    href="{{ account.extra_data.html_url }}">{{ account.extra_data.login }}</a>
    </p>

{% endfor %}
```

`extra_data.login` - showing the GitHub's login.